# Applying a function to increasingly larger subsets of a data frame

Tags: r, function, subset, lapply

I want to apply a statistical function to increasingly larger subsets of a data frame, starting at row 1 and incrementing by, say, 10 rows each time. So the first subset is rows 1-10, the second rows 1-20, and the final subset is rows 1-nrows. Can this be done without a for loop? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one solution:

```
# some sample data
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:105, 105))

#getting the endpoints of the sequences you wanted
row_seq <- c(seq(0,nrow(df), 10), nrow(df))

#getting the datasubsets filtering df from 1 to each endpoint  
data.subsets <- lapply(row_seq, function(x) df[1:x, ])

# applying the mean function to each data-set
#  just replace the function mean by whatever function you want to use
lapply(data.subsets, mean)
```